# No recibo data en Servidor (Controller) desde AJAX. CodeIgniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Tengo el siguiente ajax, donde el primer console.log tengo un arrays de objetos.

```
    document.querySelector("#generate-aumento-btn").addEventListener("click", submit)

async function submit(){
    const productosActualizados =  await productosActualizadosFuncion();
    const datosEnviar = await JSON.stringify(productosActualizados);
    // Enviar el array de objetos por AJAX
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + 'Productos/incrementarProductoPorcentaje',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({produc:datosEnviar}),
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#generate-aumento-btn').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#generate-aumento-btn').text('Aumentando...');
        },
        success: function (resp) {
            console.log(resp);
            if (!resp.success) {
                Swal.fire({
              title: 'Error!',
              text: resp.message,
              icon: 'error',
              type: 'error'
            })
              $('#generate-aumento-btn').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#generate-aumento-btn').text('Generar aumento');
            } else {
                Swal.fire({
              title: 'Mensaje',
              text: resp.message,
              type: 'success'
                }).then(function() {
                    location.reload();
            });
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            Swal.fire({
            title: 'Error',
            text: xhr.responseText,
            icon: 'error',
            type: 'error'
        })
            $('#generate-aumento-btn').attr('disabled', false);
            $('#generate-aumento-btn').text('Generar aumento');
        }
    });
}
```

La ruta es correcta.
El controller donde intento recibir la data es:

```
public function incrementarProductoPorcentaje(){
    $productos = $this->input->post("produc");
    var_dump($productos);
    if(!empty($productos)){
```

Donde el var_dump me devuelve NULL.
Intente muchas cosas como: hacer un **var_dump($_POST)**  ---   **$productos = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);** ---- luego en ajax **contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"** intente solo con **data: {produc: productosActualizados},**

pero ninguno me dio resultado. No se que puede ser

EDIT: TRAZA:

```
URL de la solicitud: http://localhost/casbas/Productos/incrementarProductoPorcentaje
Método de la solicitud: POST
Código de estado: 200 OK
Dirección remota: [::1]:80
Directiva del origen de referencia: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 25
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 03 Feb 2023 03:09:38 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98
Server: Apache/2.4.54 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1p PHP/7.4.30
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.30
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es,es-ES;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 496
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Host: localhost
Origin: http://localhost
Referer: http://localhost/casbas/aumentar-precio-porcentaje
sec-ch-ua: "Not_A Brand";v="99", "Microsoft Edge";v="109", "Chromium";v="109"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/109.0.1518.70
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: ¿Puedes pasar la traza de la llamada? y ¿exactamente que te devuelve el método?

Comment: @Grismak el metodo editaDatos de la base de datos, retorna un mensaje con el OK o el error.

Comment: @Grismak ahi edite la publicacion con la traza de la llamada